# how to login on xmrpools.net

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I read the "Getting Started" section, but i dont quite understand it.  I downloaded XMR-AEON and have it setup with my MyMonero Payment address.  Everything seems to be working, its mining, Im getting a hashrate, and when i enter my payment address in the dashboard to see my status it shows up, but i still cannot log in.

When setting up XMR, it asked for the Pool address, i entered.  My payment address, i entered.  And password.  It said I could leave it blank, put in "x", or enter my own.  I entered my own, thinking this is what I use to login on xmrpools.net.  but this doesnt seem to be the case...

Comment: same issue. Have never been able to login to this pool on the website. To track my stats on this pool I use the "enter payment address" at the bottom of the homepage, past the pool stats. Unfortunately this feature is unreliable and will not always load (same with the pool stats counter sometimes). Finally I got a 3rd party app to monitor my stats, but that has its own set of issues as its dependant on xmrpool.net for gathering the data. Really wish there was a point of contact for managing the website tools instead of just useless chat amongst all monero users for "help." After I reach my pay

Answer (score 0):

I started mining right away in the XMRPool, using my payment address as the username and [worker label]:[my email] as the password.

When I login, I paste my payment address and use my email as the password. No worker label.

In the dashboard, paste your payment address again and click `track live stats`, so you can get a nice graph and some additional information.

Comment: How long did it take before you were able to login to your account on xmrpool.net? I have been mining with 3 CPUs now for about 30 minutes, and I'm still not able to login